# Custom Application class in library project

Tags: android

I have an android library project being referenced by an application project. The library project has a custom class extending the base `Application` class where I have done some initializations. Now the problem is that this class doesn't get called automatically even though I have registered it correctly in the manifest file of the library project. I even tried to call it using

```
 MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
 app.onCreate();
```

But this gives me a null pointer exception.

What I think is that application class does not get called in the library project automatically. If this is true then what's a better way to call it manually from with in the library project?

Comment: Register the Application class in the manifest of the application project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a limitation of Android library projects. The AndroidManifest.xml of a library project is effectively ignored in a project that uses that library.

Thus you need to put any `<activity>`, `<service>`, and other such tags in the end application's manifest.

**Note**: While the above was true in 2013 (and is still true if you are using Ant as your build system), the Android Gradle plugin will merge manifests from AAR libraries into your manifest automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the response. so how do i register my library project application class in the end application. the problem is that i am using ACRA bug reporting API whic uses the Application class.

Comment: set `android:name="com.example.MyApplicationClass"` in the end application's manifest. It can reference any subclass of Application, including one defined in your library.

Comment: Thank you so much ! it worked. but doing this would mean that the end application wont be able to use its own application class it there is any ?

Comment: You can extend the library's Application class in the application project and provide any additional implementation. If you do this, you will have to use this extended Application in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you rajesh.let me try it.

Comment: The answer is very helpful as I am using my own library project which has application class in it.

Comment: @Rajesh I want to make a library for developers to use it to decrease some works. So i don't have access to their manifest or application class. What can i do now?

Comment: Being a library developer, you can require your users (through documentation) to use your Application class or its extension in their manifest.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde ... it's even better if you just create your own class which can be used from anywhere, imagine if you have two libraries which "require" you to use their own Application class, you can't extend both, because Java. Take a look at the following for good examples: [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#setup), [ANR-Watchdog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog#how-to-use-with-gradle--android-studio) and [old Glide way](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration/b3641efda7d78ec75019f0e4b387f977a7364d37#in-your-application) (the new one is also an interesting read)

Comment: This is not true (at least not anymore): a library's Manifest is merged with the application's so that anything declared in the library will work in the application.

Comment: I mean yeah, but this answer is from 2013 when it very much was true. I'll add a note.

Comment: This link has a better solution: https://proandroiddev.com/your-android-libraries-should-not-ask-an-application-context-51986cc140d4